# Do I add the bonus to my previous modifier or do I exchange my previous modifier for it when I use spells like Pass Without Trace?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Pass Without Trace gives the player a +10 bonus to stealth checks. Would I add 10 to my initial stealth modifier or swap it for +10?

If I had a +2 stealth mod and use the spell would I have +12 or +10?

Answer (score 16):

### You have +12

It's a **bonus**, and generally, bonuses stack, so you add it to your current Dexterity (Stealth) modifier. Much like how you add your Proficiency **bonus** to your Dexterity (stealth) modifier if you are proficient in stealth.